# Handle Spring Security Exception CXF

Tags: spring-security, cxf, jax-ws, interceptor

Hi i have created this class to handle all spring security exception :

```
                import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault;
                import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
                import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
                import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
                import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
                import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
                import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
                import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
                import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

                /**
                 * The Class SoapAuthenticationInterceptor.
                 */
                public class SoapAuthenticationInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> implements InitializingBean {

                    /** The authentication manager. */
                    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

                    /** The authentication required. */
                    private boolean authenticationRequired = true;

                    /**
                     * Instantiates a new soap authentication interceptor.
                     */
                    public SoapAuthenticationInterceptor() {
                        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
                    }

                    /**
                     * Sets the authentication manager.
                     *
                     * @param authenticationManager
                     *            the new authentication manager
                     */
                    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
                        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Sets the authentication required.
                     *
                     * @param authenticationRequired
                     *            the new authentication required
                     */
                    public void setAuthenticationRequired(boolean authenticationRequired) {
                        this.authenticationRequired = authenticationRequired;
                    }

                    /*
                     * (non-Javadoc)
                     * 
                     * @see
                     * org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet()
                     */
                    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
                        if (authenticationManager == null) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("No authentication manager has been configured");
                        }
                    }

                    /*
                     * (non-Javadoc)
                     * 
                     * @see org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Interceptor#handleMessage(org.apache.cxf.
                     * message.Message)
                     */
                    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
                        Authentication authentication = message.getExchange().get(Authentication.class);
                        if (authentication != null) {
                            try {
                                authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
                                message.getExchange().put(Authentication.class, authentication);
                            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                                throw new SoapFault("Bad credentials", message.getVersion().getSender());
                            }
                        } else if (authenticationRequired) {
                            throw new SoapFault("Authentication required", message.getVersion().getSender());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

then in my applicationContext.xml i have configured this intercepter like this:

```
            <bean id="soapAuthenticationInterceptor" class="com.test.cxf.interceptors.SoapAuthenticationInterceptor">
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
            </bean>

            <cxf:bus>
                <cxf:features>
                    <cxf:logging />
                </cxf:features>
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <ref bean="soapAuthenticationInterceptor" />
                </cxf:inInterceptors>
                <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
                    <ref bean="soapAuthenticationInterceptor" />
                </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            </cxf:bus>
```

my probleme is when i send a soapui enveloppe with a bad login/password the Interceptor is not called ?

can you please help me ?

Comment: have you defined the class authenticationManager that you are 'ref'erring to?

Comment: yes the code work fine and no exception

Comment: ok. you said the interceptor is not called when you send a bad login/pwd. Does it get invoked otherwise?

Comment: the interceptor is invoked when i login successfully with spring security but not befor login/password  fault

Comment: response is here : [Solution is a filter not an interceptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458497/spring-security-exception-and-cxf-jax-ws) but still another problem .

Comment: Filter is a solution if you are using JAX-RS. Chk this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37253238/5934435 . for JAX-WS, Interceptor is the right way to go.

Comment: implement a callback and that should be it.

Comment: thanks Sampada, i use jax-ws, do you have an example to implemenation of callback ? because the problem here is the spring security filter is called befor cxfservelet see my problem here :stackoverflow.com/a/37253238/5934435

Comment: were you able to resolve this @Morad ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th solution is to override [DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://www.threadstuck.com/question/handle-unauthorized-error-soap-message-digest-authentication-spring-security/).for the code class is in this [url](http://www.threadstuck.com/question/handle-unauthorized-error-soap-message-digest-authentication-spring-security/)